# Add Existing Solution To a Local Git Server (Kalithea) Repository From Visual Studio 2017

Tags: git, server, version-control, visual-studio-2017

I would like to add my existing my solution (.sln) in visual studio 2017 to a git server (using Kalithea). The issue is that the solution is already being connected to a team foundation server online.

I would like to add the local git server as the primary git repository and manage the source control using Kalithea.

I already have kalithea installed on the server and git is already installed.

If you guys can help me out that would be awesome.

Thank you very much in advance and best regards,

Comment: I don't know Kalithea but the steps should be: 1. Create a git repository in Kalithea 2. Add the url of this repository as a remote in your local repository (or change the one pointing toward tfs online) 3. push to this remote.